# How to deserialize from xml file to object list in java?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, simple-framework

The following code doesn't work. I got exception when I run these line[Object objPoints = serializer.read(Point.class, file);] In details, the source attachment doesn't contain the source for the Persister.class.

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer; 
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import java.io.File;

Serializer serializer = new Persister();
File file = new File("1.xml");
Object objPoints = serializer.read(Point.class, file);
```

Point Class is as follow :

```
@Root
public class Point {
   @Element
   private float X;
   @Element
   private float Y;
}
```

I references from [this link](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).

Comment: What is the library you use? What's the `Serializer` class?

Comment: Also i am almost convinced the method will be called `read` not `rea` and `file` will be passed in without the leading `>`. Make sure you post your real code, please.

Comment: @Boris,I import [import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;]

Comment: What does "Serialization doesn't work." mean? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Also include the content of the xml file you are trying to parse

Comment: Yes, When I run these line[Object objPoints = serializer.read(Point.class, file);], I got source not found exception. In details, the source attachment doesn't contain the source for the Persister.class.

Comment: @Yu Li Shein, please edit your question itself and add details there. I have added your imports in the question.

Comment: @Boris, My xml format is <Point><X>2</X><Y>3</Y></Point>.

Comment: Add the exception stack trace to your question. Also edit it and add all other additional data you posted in comments up to now.

Answer (score 1):

If i use the xml from your comment and your code it works:

**XML:**

```
<Point>
   <X>2</X>
   <Y>3</Y>
</Point>
```

But in the title of this question you talk about "object list" - can you be more detailed here?

If you need do deserialize a list of Points you cant use the `Point` class but a list.

Btw. does your xml file contain any additional content or only this one point?

Comment: Really? I don't know what's the problem. My code does work for me. Actually I need to read the list of object. But I couldn't read one object. After reading one obeject successfully, I wonna try the list of object.

Comment: You can't read only one `Point` out of a XML Point List (eg. `<points><point>..</point><point>..</point></points>`). But what you can do is creating a `PointList` class which contains a list of `Point`s. Such a list (incl. all objects in it) can be deserialized.